# Isometric transformation matrix html5 / fabric js

Tags: html, canvas, fabricjs

as the title says I am trying to do some isometric view by using fabric.js (fabricjs.com).

I have a transformation matrix which i use to convert static objects into isometric (axonometric) view which looks like [0.87, -0.48, 0.87, 0.48, 0, 0] and this works perfect. But now i would like to transform moving objects into this view and that is what i can't get solved.

In this, simple as possible, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aid_emrelam/nm5vmcmr/2/) you can see what I am trying.

Some words to the fiddle:

The rectangle in the background is a static object which has got the      transformation matrix shown above. This object should only be a control object for the transformation.

The circle will in this case stay where it is and will be used as "anchor" for the line.

The triangle is the problem object which i can't get transformed as it should be.

If you press "transform triangle" the matrix above will be applied to the triangle and on the "upper right" position it looks good. Now if you press "Position2" the triangle will be repositioned and you will see that the transformation matrix is wrong for that position.

I am now trying to find a solution for transforming the triangle on what ever position this one is.

In this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aid_emrelam/49oLm7L6/) you will find rotating triangles on canvas without fabric.

But I just cant find the way to apply this to my objects in fabric.

Thanks in advance for answering, or pushing me into the right direction.

Sorry if I am breaking any rules about posting but this is my first time on SO.
If I have broke any rules please just say a word what I need to change. Thank you
Code of the first fiddle

```
 //isometric arrow
canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

    var rect = new fabric.Rect({
         left: canvas.getWidth()/4
        ,top: canvas.getHeight()/4
        ,originX: 'left'
        ,originY: 'top'
        ,width: canvas.getWidth()/2
        ,height: canvas.getHeight()/2
        ,name:'testRect'
        ,fill: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.2)'
    ,selectable: false
    ,transformMatrix: [0.87415728, -0.48564293, 0.87415728, 0.48564293, 0, 0]
    });
  var circle = new fabric.Circle({
     radius: 10
    ,name: 'startCircle'
    ,stroke: 'blue'
    ,strokeWidth: 2
    ,fill: 'blue'
        ,left: canvas.getWidth()/4
        ,top: canvas.getHeight()/2
    ,originX: 'center'
    ,originY: 'center'
    ,angle: 0
    ,startAngle: 0 * (Math.PI / 180)
    ,endAngle: 360 * (Math.PI / 180)
    ,transformMatrix: [0.87415728, -0.48564293, 0.87415728, 0.48564293, 0, 0]
  });
  var triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
     left: 390
    ,top: 170
    ,name: 'triAngle'
    ,width: 150
    ,height: 150
    ,selectable: true
    ,originX: 'center'
    ,originY: 'center'
    ,angle: 0
    ,centeredRotation: false
    //,transformMatrix: [0.87415728, -0.48564293, 0.87415728, 0.48564293, 0, 0]
  });
  var line = new fabric.Line([circle.left, circle.top, triangle.left, triangle.top], {
     name: 'theLine'
    ,fill: 'blue'
    ,stroke: 'blue'
    ,originX: 'center'
    ,originY: 'center'
    ,selectable: false
    ,groupSelection: false
  });
    canvas.add(rect, circle, triangle, line);
  triangle.set({'angle':checkAngle(circle, triangle)});
    canvas.renderAll();

  triangle.on('moving', function(){
    canvas.item(2).set({'angle':checkAngle(canvas.item(1), canvas.item(2))});
    canvas.item(3).set({
        'x2':this.getLeft(),
      'y2':this.getTop()
    });
  });

  function checkAngle(circle, triangle){
        var p1 = { x: circle.left, y: circle.top };
      var p2 = { x: triangle.left, y: triangle.top };
      if(triangle.transformMatrix){
        return (Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180 / Math.PI)
      } else {
        return (Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180 / Math.PI)+90;
      }      
  }

  $("#transformTriangle").on("click",function(){
    canvas.item(2).set({
      transformMatrix: [0.87415728, -0.48564293, 0.87415728, 0.48564293, 0, 0]
    });
    canvas.item(2).set({
      angle: checkAngle(canvas.item(1), canvas.item(2))
    });
    canvas.renderAll();
  });

  $("#pos2").on("click",function(){
    canvas.item(2).set({
        left: 410,
      top: 464,
      angle: checkAngle(canvas.item(1), canvas.item(2))
    });
    canvas.item(2).setCoords();
    canvas.item(2).fire('moving');
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nm5vmcmr/3/  i hope i could figure it out, but i can't. check the udpated fiddle.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi Thanks for your try, I have tried a similar solution on my own but I also didn't get it.

I figured it out that if you add +11° to the var angle1 = (angle+11) / 180 * Math.PI; at line 78 the triangle will fit on position2 better then before. 

Do you have any other Ideas? I will try to make some graphics as control objects in the background so we will have a better way to control the transformations